# How to bind NodaTime.Duration using System.CommandLine?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, console-application, nodatime

Is it possible to directly bind command line input to `NodaTime.Duration` (or `System.TimeSpan`) using `System.CommandLine`? Maybe by supplying a custom converter somewhere?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rootCommand = new RootCommand
    {
        new Option<Duration>("--my-duration"),
    };

    rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create(
        (Duration myDuration) => { Console.WriteLine(myDuration); });

    rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with `System.CommandLine` much, and there's not much documentation around custom parsing, but I believe what you want is a `ParseArgument<T>`. Fortunately it's fairly easy to write that an extension method on the NodaTime `IPattern<T>` to create an instance of that.

Here's a not-very-thoroughly-tested extension method:

```cs
using NodaTime.Text;
using System.CommandLine.Parsing;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class PatternExtensions
    {
        public static ParseArgument<T> ToParseArgument<T>(this IPattern<T> pattern) =>
            result => ParseResult<T>(pattern, result);

        private static T ParseResult<T>(IPattern<T> pattern, ArgumentResult result)
        {
            // TODO: Check whether Tokens is actually what we want to use.
            if (result.Tokens.Count != 1)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = "Only a single token can be parsed";
                return default;
            }
            var token = result.Tokens[0];
            var nodaResult = pattern.Parse(token.Value);
            if (nodaResult.Success)
            {
                return nodaResult.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = nodaResult.Exception.Message;
                return default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And code to use it:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System;
using System.CommandLine;
using System.CommandLine.Invocation;
using Demo; // To make the extension method available

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootCommand = new RootCommand
        {
            new Option<Duration>(
                "--my-duration",
                DurationPattern.JsonRoundtrip.ToParseArgument()),
        };

        rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create(
            (Duration myDuration) => Console.WriteLine(myDuration));

        rootCommand.Invoke(args);
    }
}
```

The pattern being parsed (`DurationPattern.JsonRoundtrip`) uses "number of hours" as the most significant part, whereas the default format (used by `Console.WriteLine` in this case) uses "number of days", so it's easy to tell that it really is parsing:

```
$ dotnet run -- --my-duration=27:23:45
1:03:23:45
```